# System Restore error 0xc0000225 due to Anti Virus Update 0x80070005

Tags: windows-8.1, anti-virus, system-restore, avast

Really need some advice, as I don't know what to do now!

I was using my computer as normal and had an Avast Anti Virus message pop up along the lines of, "Avast update restart computer?" I clicked on yes. On start up it showed a blue screen and the following system error 0xc0000225.

I then held down the power key and tried to trouble shoot by trying to restore the system to a previous date. I encountered the following error:
"System restore could not access a file because an antivirus program is running on the computer. Temporarily disable your antivirus program and retry system restore.
An unspecified error occurred during system restore (0x80070005)"

How would I disable the antivirus if I can't even get into my computer?

btw my operating system is windows 8.1

Thanks a million!

Comment: Have you tried to boot into safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had a problem with my PC so I did a system restore without disabling Avast antivirus. I ended up getting a 0xc0000225 error, trying safe mode simply rebooted the computer. After doing every fix I could think of, system restore from boot drive, startup repair, chkdsk /r, sfc, manually copying system files.. all failed to fix the problem. I found a fix online that repaired the problem:

Boot from a recovery drive or DVD. (There are a lot of tutorials on how to do this.)

1. Invoke command prompt.
2. Run DISKPART and select your system drive (usually drive 0) with the command `select disk 0` then enter the command `list volume`.
3. Find the volume that is labeled "system reserved". It should be 100MB.
   Find the drive letter of this volume and select it with the command `select volume #` (replace the # symbol with the drive letter.).
4. Assign it a new drive letter. Use any available letter, I will use `X` as my example. Enter the command `assign letter x`
5. Exit diskpart. Enter the command `exit` This will get you back to the command prompt.
6. Rebuild the system reserved partition. Enter the command `bcdboot C:\windows /s x: /f uefi`. Remember if you used a different drive letter than in my example, type it instead of `X`.
7. Exit command prompt with the command `exit` and reboot the computer.

You will now have an additional option on your bootloader. You must select the new one that corresponds with the new system volume.